SourceTree: Files list window in the FiIe Status view not displaying changed files
For some reason, the Files list window in the File Status view disappeared and I'm not able to restore it:

I'm running OSX and so far I have replaced the app (w/o removing it) and did not solved my problem. Is there any way to get it back without removing Sourcetree?

broo, you need to delete this file
/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Library/Preferences/com.torusknot.SourceTreeNotMAS.plist

@chigarow Nice! That fixed my problem. You can post it as the answer to my issue. Thanks!

/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Library/Preferences/com.torusknot.SourceTreeNotMAS.plist
Can delete this file bro
